# VBS If Variable > Variable Then

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, hta

I am writing a script to delete folders older than a certain time window.

The issue I am having is with an If then statement.

```
If strCurrentAge > strAgeCutoff Then
```

strCurrentAge = date diff calculation (calculates days between now and the last modified date of the folder)

```
strAgeCutOff = AgeCutOff.value (textbox input value from an HTA... Typical value would be 30)
```

`strAgeCutOff` as a number.

strCurrentAge seems to be recognized as a number though.

Banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

Comment: Show your actual code. Where is strCurrentAge coming from?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the entire script, but the strCurrentAge work fine when I replace strAgeCuttOff with an actual number Example: If strCurrentAge > 30 Then

Comment: We can't possibly debug code for you that you don't include in your question.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to diagnose without more code, otherwise all anyone would be able to do is make a stab in the dark. What is the error you're getting? You could try explicitly casting it to an Int or Dbl using `Cint(strAgeCutOff)`  or `CDbl(strAgeCutOff)` as appropriate, but that could be a hammer solution to a screw problem - it'll work, but it might be wrong.

Comment: At this point I believe it is less of a bug and more of a can it be done? I'm away from work right now and cannot post the script. I will tomorrow. Was hoping someone was going to tell me it could or could not be done.

Comment: Thanks Ghost... I tried Int() but no luck... I will try your idea tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `AgeCutOff` is a *text* box, then `AgeCutOff.value` won't actually be a number, it will be text.

If you want a number from it, look into the `CInt()` function. You could also use `CLng` for a greater range but, unless you're talking about the ages of thngs that live substantially longer than humans, integers up to 32,000 should suffice.

Comment: Got ya... I will try that. I was trying Int() but no luck.